# Disable module member contents in sphinx autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using sphinx to autodoc a python module. For instance, my code like this in file test.py:

```
Number2Name = {'1': u'中文', '3': u'英文'}
"""
字典数据结构 # Dictionary data structures
"""
```

When I write this in rst file:

```
.. automodule:: test
    :members:
```

It will generate correct html page, but with Unicode strings instead of Chinese characters, like:

```
test.Number2Name={'1': u'\u4e2d\u6587', '3': u'\u82f1\u6587'}
字典数据类型结构
```

When the data gets more and more information in it, this become annoying cause it offers non-readable information while take lots of place in the html page.

So I wonder if Sphinx can disable showing the value of the variable in the module. Making the page like this:

```
test.Number2Name
字典数据类型结构
```

I read http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc but cannot find a solution. I guess I should modify sphinx source code to support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the write file if it is coding in UTF8. Press save as another,you can choose the coding(Default coding is ANSI)

Comment: yes, the script starts with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and the script can run successfully.